# how to process code in flash as3 without adding event listener (as soon as flash discovers it)

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to fetch some data from php to flash and print it in a dynamic text field. I know this might be a silly question but i cant seem to work out how to get flash to process the code text_field.text = data.return_msg; without it needing an event listener.

So i want the code to be processed as soon as flash discovers it basically.

this is what i have at the moment:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("get_blog_info.php");


// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;


trace(varLoader);


var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
title_txt.text = data.return_msg;
}
```

and i get this error:

"1120: Access of undefined property event."

I know its a basic question, but i'm new to flash so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually listen to your loader in order to detect when it receives a response from PHP.  Only then will you have an event object, and a populated data property.  You should be doing something like this:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("get_blog_info.php"));

function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded); // recomended, to prevent memory leaks. if you will not be using this loader again.
    title_txt.text = evt.target.data;
}
```

I've deliberately ignored your use of `URLVariables` as I believe you have misunderstood its purpose.  You would create an instance of URLVariables with a string of name/value pairs, which are variables that will get sent to your PHP script.  Since you don't seem to be using any variables for the request I have ignored it

Comment: hey. Just tried the code you suggested. It doesn't seem to return any data as nothing is showing up. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested your PHP script on its own in a browser to make sure it is outputting as expected?

Comment: Yes i have. Just done another check now. Everything is working fine in the php. I do have one included file which ive just tried to remove and still nothing from flash so i'm pretty sure the problems not coming from php.

Comment: ah, got it working. It was a silly mistake i made when editing the code a little. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Web requests are asynchronous-only in Flash. You have no choice but to add an event listener to be informed when the load has completed, at which time you can access the data.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data) shows the only way to do what you're looking for. You have to wait until it receives the information back from the request to display the text:

```
// notice: you want to have a request which points to the URL, not the variables.
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("get_blog_info.php");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
// it looks like you just want a string returned.
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event):void {
    title_txt.text = urlLoader.data;
}
```

Comment: hey, just tried your code. All that seems to appear is "<?" in the text field. It also shows up in the text field in the .fla file so the "<?" is not coming from the php. Thanks.